# Will updating cx_Oracle break any running code?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

So I ran a program and got an error saying `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library is at version 11.1 but version 11.2 or higher is needed`

The issue is I have other programs running on `version 11.1` but I need to update to `11.2 or higher` to run specific code.

If I upgrade my `cx_Oracle` will this break any other instances of code running with respect to `version 11.1`?

If you cannot do it, or if there is a better way, what would be the best way to deal with this?

Comment: To avoid impact to other code, for the apps that need an updated stack, you can use some kind of wrapper script (shell script or batch file, depending on OS) that sets the library search path (LD_LIBRARY_PATH or PATH, depending on OS) to the updated Oracle Client library path.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone can give you assurances that upgrading your Oracle Client library won't break any of your code! It is going to depend highly on what kind of code you have and whether you have done anything unexpected in that code. So you need to perform the upgrade and test your applications yourself. A great deal of effort is made to ensure a seamless upgrade experience but a seamless upgrade cannot be guaranteed!

With the instant client you have the option of easily installing a separate version for your new application. You just need to make sure that you select the correct configuration for each different application. This gives you the option of testing each application independently.

Answer (score 1):

You could install multiple versions of the client library and use the one you prefer with:

```
cx_Oracle_init_client(lib_dir="/path/where/my/lib/")
```

More info [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html?highlight=init_oracle_client#using-cx-oracle-init-oracle-client-to-set-the-oracle-client-directory)